# Java - Normalize and serialize a nested tree structure with Jackon

Tags: java, jackson

So I have a bi-directional graph which looks kind of like the following:

```java
class Node {
    private String name
    private Node[] next;
    private Node[] previous;
    // ...
}
```

When I serialize this using Jackson and the following annotation: `JsonIdentityInfo` it works just fine and I get something like the following:

```
{
  "@id": 1,
  "name": "node1",
  "next": [
    {
       "@id": 2,
       "name": "node2",
       "next": [
         {
            "@id": 3,
            "name": "node3",
            "next": [],
            "previous": [2]
         }   
       ],
       "previous": [1]
    }
  ],
  "previous": []
}
```

Where it serializes the nested structure but avoids cyclic recursion by defining the node the first time its encountered then using its id for all other references.

This is good but I was wondering if it was possible to instead get something like the following instead:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "@id": 1,
            "name": "node1",
            "next": [2],
            "previous": []
        },
        {
            "@id": 2,
            "name": "node2",
            "next": [3],
            "previous": [1]
        },
        {
            "@id": 3,
            "name": "node3",
            "next": [],
            "previous": [2]
        }
    ]
}
```

Where the nesting is completely removed and the node id is used every time.

Is it possible to achieve this easily/quickly with Jackson? whereby I don't need to define a full custom serializer/deserializer

Comment: Not directly a solution, but I would move this in the DTO-transformation, i.e. the DTOs should have a `List<Integer> next` and `List<Integer> prev`.

Comment: so basically have `toDTO` and `fromDTO` functions somewhere and just serialize the DTOs instead?

Comment: Ytes. This comment was 10 characters to short.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to add jackson's annotation :

```
class Node {
    private String name
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private Node[] next;
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private Node[] previous;
    // ...
}
```

Then load/query all your nodes as a list and serialize them using Jackson you will get the structure that you want.